# Error after decompil c# XML plugin for NopCommerce

Tags: c#, xml, plugins, nopcommerce

I get errors when I decompile my code. It's a syntax I don't understand and I don't know how to fix it, can you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeuLv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isy7a.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw4q3.png)

```
public void performrolemapping(Customer customer, bool newcustomer)
    {
        if (!newcustomer)
        {
            IList<CustomerRole> customerRoles = this._customerservice.GetCustomerRoles(customer, false);
            Func<CustomerRole, bool> u003cu003e9_170 = ParagonAuthenticationController.<> c.<> 9__17_0;
            if (u003cu003e9_170 == null)
            {
                u003cu003e9_170 = new Func<CustomerRole, bool>(ParagonAuthenticationController.<> c.<> 9, (CustomerRole cr) => cr.get_SystemName() == NopCustomerDefaults.get_RegisteredRoleName());
                ParagonAuthenticationController.<> c.<> 9__17_0 = u003cu003e9_170;
            }
            if ((object)Enumerable.FirstOrDefault<CustomerRole>(customerRoles, u003cu003e9_170) != (object)null)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        IList<CustomerRole> allCustomerRoles = this._customerservice.GetAllCustomerRoles(true);
        List<CustomerRole> list = new List<CustomerRole>();
        foreach (CustomerRole allCustomerRole in allCustomerRoles)
        {
            list.Add(allCustomerRole);
        }
        foreach (CustomerRole customerRole in list)
        {
            if (customerRole.Name != "Registered")
            {
                continue;
            }
            ICustomerService customerService = this._customerservice;
            CustomerCustomerRoleMapping customerCustomerRoleMapping = new CustomerCustomerRoleMapping();
            customerCustomerRoleMapping.CustomerId = customer.Id;
            customerCustomerRoleMapping.CustomerRoleId = customerRole.Id;
            customerService.AddCustomerRoleMapping(customerCustomerRoleMapping);
            return;
        }
    }

    public static string RandomString()
    {
        ParagonAuthenticationController.<> c__DisplayClass18_0 variable = null;
        int num = 40;
        Random random = new Random();
        return new string(Enumerable.ToArray<char>(Enumerable.Select<string, char>(Enumerable.Repeat<string>("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*+", num), new Func<string, char>(variable, (string s) => s[this.random.Next(s.get_Length())]))));
    }
```

Comment: Looks like it is obfuscated in some way, why would you decompile you own code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I decompile to have the code. It was a .dll

Comment: Maybe you are trying to get some logic from a third-party vendor plugin using ILSpy. It will be tough to say what is the exact solution.